# Show that $k[x]/(x^{2})$ is an indecomposable (1), but not irreducible (2) $k[x]$-module.

Tags: representation-theory, modules

**Exercise:** Show that $k[x]/(x^{2})$ is an indecomposable (1), but not irreducible (2) $k[x]$-module.

---

I'm not sure about all different kind of modules, but this is a question of a book about associative algebras. It is not really exercise, it is just stated in the text, so  I guess it must be rather trivial, but I'm not getting it. I think it may be I forgot some old ring theory/linear algebra stuff.

If I understand correctly: $k[x]/(x^{2})$ can be seen as $\{a+bx: a,b \in k\}$.

So for (1), I must show that there don't exist two non-zero representation $V_{1},V_{2}$ of $k[x]$so that $k[x]/(x^{2})$ is isomorphic to $V_{1}\oplus V_{2}$. Well as $k[x]/(x^{2})$ is 2 dimensional. $V_{1},V_{2}$ have to be $1$ dimensional. But I'm not sure how the 1-dimensional subrepresentation look like. Are they just isomorphic to $k$ ?

For (2), I need to show there exist an non-trivial subrepresention. So I have to show there exists a subspace $W$ of $\{a+bx: a,b \in k\}$ such that $fW \subset W$ for any polynomial $f$. Well, that seems impossible to me. I can't think of any if $W=k$, then $x\cdot \alpha$ is not in $W$. If $W=\{bx:b\in k\}$ then $bx bx$ is not in $W$.

---

**I feel like I look at this the complete wrong way, feel free to ignore all my stuff above, and show me a way how to look at this. :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) A one-dimensional space over $k$ *always* looks like $k$.  Think about what copies of $k$ there are, and which ones are invariant.

2) Why do you say that $bxbx\notin W$?  $bxbx = b^2 x^2 = 0 \in W$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm seeing 2) now. For 1), $k \oplus k$ ,isn't that just $k^2$? I'm not sure why $k^2$ isn't isomorphic to $\{a+bx :a,b\in k\}$.

Comment: @Kasper obviously they're the same vector space, but what about multiplicative structure? If you believe they are isomorphic, why do you think that, and what do you think the isomorphism would be?

Comment: @anon, oh wait, I think I may get it. Something like $x(a+bx)=xa+b= b \oplus a$, while $x(a\oplus b)=xa \oplus xb$ ?

Comment: @Kasper $x$ is not an element of $k$, so it's not clear what you mean by the second equation.  There is no natural action of $k[x]$ on $k^2$.

Comment: My book says: "Let $V_1,V_2$ be representations of an algebra $A$. Then the space $V_1 \oplus V_2$ has an obvious structure of a representation of $A$, given by $a(v_1 \oplus v_2) = av_1 \oplus v_2$. This representation is called the direct sum of $V_1,V_2$." So I thought $A=k[x]$ and $V_1,V_2=k$.

Comment: @Kasper But writing $k\oplus k$ is not the direct sum of representations, just of vector spaces.  You need to say what the action on $k$ is before you can write $V_1=k$ etc. and apply that construction.  For example, say that $k=\mathbb{Q}$.  What is $x\cdot \frac{1}{2}$, as a rational number?  It's meaningless until you specify how $x$ is transforming the space (note that it isn't so hard to find all the ways this can happen; any transformation of a 1-dimensional space is multiplication by a scalar).

Comment: Ah, okay, this goes quite deep, I'm going to think about it, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

For a field $k$, $k[x]$ is a principal ideal ring. By the correspondence theorem, the only ideals of $k[x]/(x^2)$ are those generated by divisors of $x^2$. Thus $k[x]/(x^2)$ has exactly three submodules: $(x^2)/(x^2),(x)/(x^2)$ and $k[x]/(x^2)$.

So the existence of $(x)/(x^2)$ immediately tells you why $k[x]/(x^2)$ isn't irreducible. And how could it be directly decomposable? There is only one proper ideal, so there isn't a second proper ideal to complement the first. So, there isn't a nontrivial decomposition of $k[x]/(x^2)$